How Can I Avoid Calls to js.arcgis.com From My Javascript pp
I'm building a JavaScript app with the ArcGis JavaScript SDK.  We have a requirement that the app should run on prem without external dependencies. How can I use the SDK without it making calls to js.arcgis.com?
here is my package.json
{
  "engines": {
    "npm": ">=10.8.3 <=10.8.3",
    "node": ">=22.9.0 <=22.9.0"
},
  "name": "buildingmonitor",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
  "dev": "vite",
  "build": "tsc -b && vite build && npm run copyAssets",
  "lint": "eslint .",
  "preview": "vite preview --port 5173",
  "postinstall": "npm run copyAssets",
  "copyAssets": "shx mkdir -p ./public/assets && shx cp -r node_modules/@esri/calcite-components/dist/calcite/assets/* ./public/assets/",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@arcgis/map-components-react": "^4.31.6",
    "@esri/arcgis-rest-auth": "^3.7.0",
    "@esri/arcgis-rest-request": "^4.2.3",
    "@esri/calcite-components-react": "^2.13.2",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "react-router": "^7.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@eslint/js": "^9.15.0",
    "@types/node": "^22.10.2",
    "@types/react": "^18.3.12",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "@types/react-modal": "^3.16.3",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.3.4",
    "eslint": "^9.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.37.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.14",
    "globals": "^15.12.0",
    "shx": "^0.3.4",
    "typescript": "~5.6.2",
    "typescript-eslint": "^8.15.0",
    "vite": "^6.0.0"
  }
}

When I look at my network tab I can see a lot of calls to js.argis.com, and I found that domain hard coded in arcgis node modules folders:

When I inspect my app with dev tools, I see a lot of network calls to js.arcgis.com:

Map Widget:
import "@arcgis/map-components/dist/components/arcgis-map";
import { ArcgisMap } from "@arcgis/map-components-react";
import { ArcgisMapCustomEvent } from "@arcgis/map-components/dist/types";

const MapWidget = () => {
  const handleMapReady = (event: ArcgisMapCustomEvent<void>) => {};

  return (
    <ArcgisMap
      onArcgisViewReadyChange={handleMapReady}
    />
  );
};

export default MapWidget;


When building from npm, and to use local assets there are two steps: (1) copying the assets and (2) configure the asset paths in your code/
It looks like you're only doing step 1. You need to also set the assets path.
The hardcoded paths you're seeing is just the default.
Refs:

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/get-started-npm/#working-with-assets
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/disconnected-environment/



Download the ArcGIS JavasScript library

unzip and copy the contents into your react app public folder

create a service-worker.js file:
self.addEventListener('install', (event) => {
  const extendableEvent = event;
  extendableEvent.waitUntil(self.skipWaiting());
});


self.addEventListener('activate', (event) => {
  const extendableEvent = event;
  extendableEvent.waitUntil(self.clients.claim());
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
  console.log('Intercepting request:', event.request.url);
  try{

    const fetchEvent = event;
    const url = new URL(fetchEvent.request.url);
    if (url.href.startsWith('https://js.arcgis.com')) {
      console.log("rewriting url", url.href);
      const newUrl = url.href.replace('https://js.arcgis.com', `${self.location.protocol}//${self.location.hostname}:${self.location.port}/arcgis/javascript`);
      console.log("new url", newUrl);
      fetchEvent.respondWith(
        fetch(newUrl, {
          mode: 'cors', // Ensure CORS mode is set
          credentials: 'same-origin', // Include credentials if needed
          headers: {
            ...fetchEvent.request.headers,
            'Origin': self.location.origin // Set the Origin header
          }
        })
      );
    } else {
      fetchEvent.respondWith(fetch(fetchEvent.request));
    }
  } catch(err){
    console.error(err);
  }
});





register the service worker before creating you app root
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js', {scope: `/`}) 
    .then((registration) => {
      console.log('Service Worker registered with scope:', registration.scope);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error('Service Worker registration failed:', error);
    });
}




The user is asking for help when building locally. There's no need to download the "CDN" version locally in this case.
